# Issue using perl to find the depth of a folder using recursion

Tags: perl, recursion

I'm using a Perl program to find the depth of a folder , i.e. number of sub-directories inside.
The problem I'm facing is that sometimes my function doesn't work and I've tried to debug it but I wasn't able to make sense of why it wouldn't work.

I have written the following line of code:

```
{
    sub max_cols {
        my ($root) = @_;
        $root .= '/';
        for my $f (glob "$root*"){
            if (-d $f)
            {
                $counter ++; 
                max_cols($f);
                if( $counter> $max_count)
                {
                    $max_count = $counter;
                }
                $counter =0;
            }
        }
        return $max_count;
    }
}
$col_number = max_cols($path);  ## $path is /*****/Task9
print $col_number;
```

Here the output was 4, but when I dove into Task9 folder, and ran the same code my output was still 4.

i.e. when the $path variable was /*****/Task9/new the output was still 4 whereas it should be 3

Answer (score 1):

Using [glob](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#glob) is problematic with dynamic input: it uses whitespace to separate patterns, so if there's a path with a space in its name somewhere, the results will be wrong. See [File::Glob::bsd_glob](https://perldoc.pl/File::Glob#bsd_glob) for an alternative.

Using recursion seems like a good idea, but you seem to not be using [strict](https://perldoc.pl/strict), which means the undeclared variables `$counter` and `$max_count` are global. For the maximum, it seems right, but the counter is never reset when returning back from a depth.

This seems to work correctly:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::Glob qw{ bsd_glob };

sub max_depth {
    my ($path, $depth) = @_;
    $depth //= 0;
    my $max = 0;
    for my $child (bsd_glob("$path/*/"), bsd_glob("$path/.*/")) {
        next if $child =~ m{/..?/$};  # Avoid endless recursion.

        my $d = max_depth($child, 1);
        $max = $d if $d > $max;
    }
    return $max + $depth
}

say max_depth(shift);
```

Or one can use [opendir](https://perldoc.pl/opendir) and [readdir](https://perldoc.pl/readdir) to avoid any modules:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

sub max_depth {
    my ($path, $depth) = @_;
    $depth //= 0;
    opendir my $dir, $path or die "$path: $!";
    my $max = 0;
    while (my $child = readdir $dir) {
        next if '.' eq $child || '..' eq $child;  # Avoid endless recursion.

        if (-d "$path/$child") {
            my $d = max_depth("$path/$child", 1);
            $max = $d if $d > $max;
        }
    }
    return $max + $depth
}

say max_depth(shift);
```

Or, most trivially, use [File::Find](https://perldoc.pl/File::Find):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::Find qw{ find };

my $max_depth = 0;
find(sub {
         my $depth = $File::Find::dir =~ tr{/}{};  # Count the slashes.
         $max_depth = $depth if $depth > $max_depth;
     }, shift);
say $max_depth;
```

Comment: In the first example, you added support for spaces, but not `{`, `?`, `*`, etc.  Solution was to use `glob(quotemeta($path))`, not switching to `bsd_glob`.